# Xcode using c++ as Core for my app?

Tags: c++, xcode, ipad

I wrote a C++ command line project in Xcode 4.2 and it works.

Now I want to make it interact with Objective-C on the iPad, I mean I want my C++ code to be able to take a file specified by the GUI process it, create a temp file and then be interpreted by Objective-C.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just rename your source file to have a .mm extension, and put ObjC and C++ in the same file with the ability to call each others functions and methods. Google for Objective-C++ for more information.